# Tiempo de espera de carga de imagen ¿como mostrar la imagen solo si ya esta cargada al 100%?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tiempo de espera de carga de imagen ¿como mostrar la imagen solo si ya esta cargada al 100%?
Hola todos verán quiero solucionar un problema respecto a la carga de imágenes, por momentos tarda en cargar la imagen así [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero remplazarlo por algo como lo que tiene youtube que queda mucho mas elegante de forma que la imagen solo se muestra si ya esta cargada al 100% [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito orientación sobre ¿como hacerlo?

Comment: Bienvenido a **StackOverflow** , te recomiendo que realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y asi obtengas tu primera medalla, ademas mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para así poder ayudarte mejor, y te recomiendo subir el código que has intentado, ya que las preguntas de ayúdenme tener ninguna evidencia de investigación no son bien recibidas  por la comunidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tu imagen agregale la propiedad visibility:hidden y despues del load document en js mostrala con jquery, sería así:

```
 <img id="ImagenEjemplo" src="images/imagen.jpg" alt="Imagen ejemplo" style="visibility:hidden"/>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ImagenEjemplo").css('display':'block');
 });
 </script>
```

Recorda comprimir las imagenes y en lo posible que estén en formato webp o png8 que están optimizados para web.

Saludos!